# Customize firebaseui with ChakraUI React

Tags: reactjs, firebase, authentication, firebaseui

I'm workin in a React project with Firebase and ChakraUI. I want to use Firebase Authentication with SMS code. That's why I'm using firebaseui, everything is working fine but because of the firebaseui library I can't change the UI design.

Is there a way to customize firebaseui for SMS phone validation with my ChakraUI elements?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a really good alternative for this issue. If you follow [this youtube video](https://youtu.be/IivlA4o5RkU) you can use Firebase Authentication with SMS Code without firebaseui and keep using your chakra ui elements.

Works for me.